# Leer Cadenas Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Necesito obtener valores que estan contenidos en una cadena de tipo str separados por una "," y que al encontrar la coma, guardar ese valor en una nueva variable por ejemplo, tengo la cadena:

10.90,500,56.99

y quiero guardar los valores en una nueva variable
a = 10.90
b= 500
c= 56.99

Este es mi codigo

```
import serial, time

launchpadPort=serial.Serial('COM6', 9600, timeout=1)

while True:
    #datosLaunchpad = open("datos.csv", 'a')
    getSerialValue = launchpadPort.readline()
    b = getSerialValue.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\n')
    print(f"Prueba: {b}")
    datosLaunchpad.write(b)
    print(type(b))
```

Comment: por que quieres guardar cada valor en una variable? es complicado hacer un codigo estable ya que la cadena podria tener dos numeros o 1000 ¿No seria mejor que lo guardaras en una lista?

Comment: puesto que vienen en formato de bits ya que losd atos son recogido a traves de arduino o launchpad, encesito la base para poder recolectar las mediciones y con base a ello, empezar a trabajar en la interfaz grafica.

Comment: eso lo puedes hacer desde una lista con un loop en vez de crearte 1000 variables para 1000 valores (por ejemplo), te voy a plantear una solución con listas y a partir de eso vamos buscando opciones a lo que necesitas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacer algo como esto!

```
str="´.500.500, 652.2352, 956.2´"
n= [ float(x.lstrip(".")) if '.' in x else int(x.lstrip(".")) for x in (str[1:-1].split(",")) ]
a,b,c = n
print(n)
print(a,b,c)
```

el resultado seria:

```
[500.5, 652.2352, 956.2]
500.5 652.2352 956.2
```

Comment: hice algo parecido, ya que es un str y modifique el codigo de arduino apra que, en lugar de que muestre una coma, de un espacio y ya haciendo la conversion de str a lista/tupla con la funcion .split() obtengo un resultado similar al que me muestras xd. Pero a veces el arduino/launchpad en los primeros resultados manda algo ´.500.500, 652.2352, 956.2´ (es un ejemplo) entonces al hacer la conversion de str a tupla, lo hace bien pero al intentar convertir los valores de la tupla a float() manda errores y se cierra el programa, en tu solución, ¿Cómo podría evitarlo?. El error pasa en los 3 valores

Comment: ya lo arregle si no incluyes los simbolos estos ´ ´ solo debes cambiar str[1:-1].split(",") por str.split(",") espero por lo menos la flechita arriba :D

Comment: Por una parte, el código funciona, pero ya empecé a probar con algunos otros casos que me he puesto a pensar y dieron algunos errores, ¿Cómo podria evitar leer una línea que no cumple con tiene los valores que necesito sin que mande un error?, es necesario crear una excepcion, ¿Como le haría? Te mando un link a la foto donde estan los errores: (https://photos.app.goo.gl/Hz4sH28fChmVMW1LA)

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado con reemplazar las líneas:

```
getSerialValue = launchpadPort.readline()
b = getSerialValue.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\n')
```

por?

```
b = [int(x) for x in launchpadPort.readline().split()]
```

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'10.90,500,56.99'

Answer (score 0):

```
def agregar(a):

    temp=""
    contador=0;
    pos=0
    vec=[]
    for c in a:
        pos=pos +1
        if c==",":
            contador=contador +1  #cuenta la cantidad de comas y la posicion 
            posfinal=pos #guarda la posicion de la ultima coma

    for x in a:    #recorremos cno x la cadena a 
        if x!=",":
            temp=temp + x    #cargamos en una variable temporal
        else:
            vec.append(temp)
            temp=""        #limpiamos la variable temporal para cargar el otro numero 

    #nos falta la ultima parte de la cadena 
    vec.append(a[posfinal:])

    for a in range(contador + 1):   #contador cuenta la cantidad - 1 de numeros entre comas 
        print vec[a]  

    return vec

lista=agregar("10.90,500,56.99")
```

# aca le envías la acdena que queres separar
print lista

Comment: Probaré esté código, me da mas control, pero he visto algunos errores en la recoleccion de datos en mi arduino y launchpad, y es que a veces en lugar de mandar la estructura correcta del formato float a veces me regresa algo como .500.500,500,256.56 entonces como estan en formato de lista/tupla al intentar hacer la conversion de str a float manda error y por ende se termina el programa, me ayudarías con eso?

Answer (score 0):

Esto podría funcionarte:

```
b = b'10.90,500,56.99' # el valor de ejemplo que das en bytes
b_list = b.decode("utf-8").split(",") # convierte a texto y separa los elementos por ","
float_list = [float(x) for x in b_list] # convierte los elementos de la lista en float
```

Answer (score 0):

Voy a suponer que en "b" tienes el string con los números

```
# con split(",") divides el string en una lista a partir de cada coma que encuentre
lista_numeros = [float(v) for v in b.split(",")]

# aquí vamos a comprobar el  tipo de variable
for i in lista_numeros:
    print(type(i))
```

No he trabajado con arduinos pero si te vale esto, me vas comentando que más necesitas y lo voy añadiendo.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
a= "10.85,56,3.21,89"
b= a.split(',')
```

Ahora `b` va a tener lo siguiente

```
["10.85", "56", "3.21", "89"]
```

puedes acceder a cada valor indicando la posicion Ej `b[0]="10.85"`
si lo quisieras como `float` seria `numero= float(b[0])`

Comment: En efecto eso hice, pero, a veces al recibir datos, me los pasa como: ".500.500, 45.6.8, 899", al hacer la conversion como tal, los valores .500.500 no tienen la estructura de flotante y madna error y al ser así, se cierra el programa.